# Heroku Rails 4 assets does not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, deployment, asset-pipeline

#### After deploy I am getting this error bellow

[image: error console chrome]

#### This is my directory

[image: directory]

#### my application.rb

[image]

Here, how I call them

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "home" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "home" %>

<img class="client" src="<%= asset_path('b.png') %>">
```

### OBS: I upgrade rails version from 3.2 to 4.0

I removed the assets groups from gemfile as recomend

```
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
```

Comment: You have to add this config  in your production configuration file: `config.serve_static_assets = true`

Comment: And also check if you have added the gem rails_12factor to your Gemfile

Comment: Yes I have gem rails_12factor and config.serve_static_assets = true.

Comment: Does `heroru run rake assets:precompile`  take any effect? Could you check if your public folder is commited?

Comment: Alvaro, I solved. The answer is bellow. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

The errors were inside `scss.erb` files. they do not call correctly helpers like `image_tag` or `asset_path`.

In my app there were so many scss.erb files like bellow.

**WRONG**

```
background: url(<%= image_path 'fake_slider.png' %>) no-repeat 0 0;
```

**RIGHT WAY**
I put them inside double quotes `" "` and everything worked.

```
background: url("<%= image_path 'fake_slider.png' %>") no-repeat 0 0;
```